# Does low battery notification on iPhone mess up or interfere with any processes currently going on

Tags: iphone

I was sending an email and while it was in sending status, the low battery notification popped up and that made me worried and paranoid because I wanted everything to go smooth as it was an important email

I checked and seen that the email did send I was just worried the recipeint got any of my info or not about the phone or if the email client did 
I’m sorry I know I’m probably being paranoid or overthinking

My question is did it mess up the email or send anything to the recepient about my phone or anything to the email client

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how this is different from your other question, please edit that one and explain why it should be reopened rather than reposting it.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do that I will just delete the other question and leave this one

Comment: @John This question will be closed as a duplicate. There's still no security question here. You should not ask the same question again if your first question is closed. If you need to make changes, there is an edit button under your question that allows you to make them. You can then flag it for re-opening or post a comment to notify other commenters that you have clarified your question. I strongly recommend that you read through the [Tour](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) sections before continuing to use StackExchange.